# Converting an array of objects into readable strings?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert an array of objects into a regular array that I can compare values against.

```
$scope.refRFRInfo

Array(6) [Object, Object, Object, …]

{Object {rfrInformationID: 3000, fiscalYear: 2020, rfrNumber: NaN, …}
```

So I have this:

```
let newArray = $scope.Info.map(a => Object.keys(a).map(k => a[k]))
```

And the results come out as:

```
Array(6) [Array(18), Array(18), Array(18), …]

Array(18) [3000, 2020, NaN, …]
```

I want the values to be labeled as their type, so "rfrInformationID" "fiscalYear" and "rfrNumber." But I don't know how to do this.

Essentially, I want to compare a single "fiscalYear" input to a list of all the $scope.Info.fiscalYear values. But it won't let me select the values for comparison when they are an object. I also need the object to remain an object so I can sort on table headers with the object intact. If there is an easier way to achieve the end result, please let me know.

EDIT:

Based on Object.entries, I came up with:

```
var map = new Map(Object.entries(results.data));
map.forEach(([key, value]) => $scope.rfrInfo.push(`${key}: ${value}`));
```

But the second line breaks. Looks to be nesting my object into another object, too.

EDIT: Here is the full function I'm working with

```
function init() {
        ContractsService.getRFRInformation()
            .then(function (results) {
                $scope.Info = results.data;
                angular.forEach($scope.Info, function (value) {
                    $scope.number.push(value.rfrNumber);
                    }
                });

                $scope.loading = false;
            });
    }
```

In the "forEach" above I passed the value of the rfrNumber only. There are 14 fields in my $scope.Info object.

Here's what I've tried:

```
                $scope.newInfo = [];

//Closest to intended result, but doesn't set names like "fiscalYear" or "rfrNumber" so
//I can't use it for validation
                $scope.Info.forEach(_ => _.rfrNumber = (+_.Number));
                let newArray = $scope.Info.map(a => Object.keys(a).map(k => a[k]));
                newArray;

//Produces result where everything is further nested
                var map = new Map(Object.entries(results.data));
                map;



//None of these are working
                map.forEach(([key, value]) => $scope.newInfo.push('${key}: ${value}'));



                for (var { Object: { rfrInformationID: ID, fiscalYear: FY, rfrNumber: number } } of results.data) {
                    $scope.newInfo.push(Object);
                }



                JSON.stringify(map);
                map;
                JSON.stringify(results.data);
                results.data;



                let {
                    results: [
                        {
                            rfrInformationID: ID,
                            fiscalYear: FY,
                            rfrNumber: number
                        },
                    ],
                } = metadata;

                }


                var arr = [];
                for (var i in results.data) {
                    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                        arr.push([i, results.data[i]]);
                    }
```

Comment: Maybe [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) is what you want.

Comment: What exactly does "compare a single `fiscalYear` input to a list of all the $scope.Info.fiscalYear values" mean? Do you want to see if a single `fiscalYear` is later than [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) `fiscalYear` in `$scope.Info`? Do you want to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out all the `$scope.Info` entries that aren't in your `fiscalYear`?

Comment: @AuxTaco First one, I want to see if a single fiscalYear is later than the entries in $scope.Info. And I want to check inputted rfrNumber to see if it was already used in $scope.Info. So there are a few validations I need to do based on property names.

Comment: @georgeawg thanks. Based on that, I came up with

 "var map = new Map(Object.entries(results.data));
map.forEach(([key, value]) => $scope.rfrInfo.push(`${key}: ${value}`)); " 

But it breaks.

Comment: JSON.stringify(array) would help.

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. Your code examples should be… **Complete** – Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Comment: @georgeawg okay, added the code